# Make New Table in SQL with same Schema

Tags: oracle, new-operator

I have a table called W_US and I want to create W_UK in oracle with same schema as for W_US.

Comment: Why do you want a separate table?  Rather than say a single table with a COUNTRY_CODE column to distinguish records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create a table called W_UK that has the same columns and types as W_US.  You could do the following:

```
create table W_UK as 
select *
  from W_US
 where 1 = 2;
```

Comment: That will create a table with the same columns specifications: names, data types, and null/not null.  It won't create any other constraints (check, foreign key, primary key, unique), grants, triggers, or other indexes.  If you need to make a new table exactly like it, look up the DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL function to get the DDL to transform it to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

These sort of questions are a warning flag, because the obvious solution is to clone the CREATE TABLE script for W_US (through the magic of 'Save as ...') and edit the clone so it creates W_UK.

The fact that this avenue appears to be closed to you suggests that you do not have your DDL statements under source control.  This is a bad state of affairs.  All our code should be under source control, including the scripts which build the database schema.